# MySQL join query taking far too long

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The following query is taking forever in MySQL 5.7.23, on a macOS 10.13.6 on 2018 Macbook Pro (A1990) with 50GB of free space:

```
INSERT INTO `a_sg1lib` (`book_id`,`title`, `isbn`, `Zstatus_retrieve_TOC`, `Zstatus_retrieve_classifybyoclc`, 
`classifybyoclc_respcode`, `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc`, `classifybyoclc_calln_ddc`, `classifybyoclc_calln_nlm`, 
`classifybyoclc_fast`, `classifybyoclc_owi`,`reference`, `data`, `crcomment`, `groupname`, `code`, `indentation`, `path`, `specialtag`, 
`specialtag_cat`, `specialtag_master`, `specialtag_master_cat`, `specialtag_override_cat_moddetails`, 
`specialtag_override_cat_timestamp`, `specialtag_override_cat`, `pageno`, `specialtag_escalated`, `history`, 
`history_classification`, `specialtag_esc_start`, `specialtag_esc_start_type`, `callCore`, 
`d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`, `d5`, `d6`, `d7`, `d8`, `d9`, `d10`, `d11`, `d12`) 
SELECT `RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc`.`ID`,`Title`, `IdentifierWODash`, `Zstatus_retrieve_TOC`, `Zstatus_retrieve_classifybyoclc`, `classifybyoclc_respcode`, `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc`, 
    `classifybyoclc_calln_ddc`, `classifybyoclc_calln_nlm`, 
    `classifybyoclc_fast`, `classifybyoclc_owi`,`reference`, `data`,
    `crcomment`, `groupname`, `code`, `indentation`, `path`, `specialtag`, `specialtag_cat`, 
    `specialtag_master`, `specialtag_master_cat`, `specialtag_override_cat_moddetails`, 
    `specialtag_override_cat_timestamp`, `specialtag_override_cat`, `pageno`, `specialtag_escalated`, `history`, 
    `history_classification`, `specialtag_esc_start`, `specialtag_esc_start_type`, `callCore`, 
    `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`, `d5`, `d6`, `d7`, `d8`, `d9`, `d10`, `d11`, `d12` 
FROM `RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc` 
RIGHT JOIN `loc_classification`.`LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY`
   ON `RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc`.`classifybyoclc_calln_lcc`=
      `loc_classification`.`LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY`.`callCore`;
```

Number of rows:

RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc - 1+ million rows - MyISAM

`LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY` - 440000+ rows - InnoDB

`a_sg1lib` - InnoDB, initially empty

Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE `RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc` (
  `ID` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(2000) DEFAULT '',
  `VolumeInfo` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `Series` varchar(300) DEFAULT '',
  `Periodical` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `Author` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  `Year` varchar(14) DEFAULT '',
  `Edition` varchar(60) DEFAULT '',
  `Publisher` varchar(400) DEFAULT '',
  `City` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `Pages` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `PagesInFile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Language` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  `Topic` varchar(500) DEFAULT '',
  `Library` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `Issue` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `Identifier` varchar(300) DEFAULT '',
  `ISSN` varchar(9) DEFAULT '',
  `ASIN` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `UDC` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `LBC` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `DDC` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `LCC` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `Doi` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `Googlebookid` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `OpenLibraryID` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `Commentary` varchar(10000) DEFAULT '',
  `DPI` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `Color` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Cleaned` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Orientation` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Paginated` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Scanned` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Bookmarked` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Searchable` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Filesize` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Extension` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `MD5` char(32) DEFAULT '',
  `Generic` char(32) DEFAULT '',
  `Visible` char(3) DEFAULT '',
  `Locator` varchar(733) DEFAULT '',
  `Local` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `TimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 13:00:00',
  `TimeLastModified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Coverurl` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `Tags` varchar(500) DEFAULT '',
  `IdentifierWODash` varchar(300) DEFAULT '',
  `Zstatus_retrieve_TOC` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zstatus_retrieve_classifybyoclc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classifybyoclc_respcode` text,
  `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classifybyoclc_calln_ddc` text,
  `classifybyoclc_calln_nlm` text,
  `classifybyoclc_fast` text,
  `classifybyoclc_owi` text,
  `classifybyoclc_timest` text,
  `pid` text,
  `ida` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MD5` (`MD5`),
  KEY `Generic` (`Generic`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisibleTimeAdded` (`Visible`,`TimeAdded`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `TimeAdded` (`TimeAdded`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Topic` (`Topic`(3)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisibleID` (`Visible`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisibleTimeLastModified` (`Visible`,`TimeLastModified`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `TimeLastModifiedID` (`TimeLastModified`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `DOI_INDEX` (`Doi`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Identifier` (`Identifier`),
  KEY `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` (`classifybyoclc_calln_lcc`),
  KEY `classifybyoclc_fast` (`classifybyoclc_fast`(300)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title` (`Title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Author` (`Author`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Language` (`Language`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Extension` (`Extension`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Publisher` (`Publisher`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Series` (`Series`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Year` (`Year`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title1` (`Title`,`Author`,`Series`,`Publisher`,`Year`,`Periodical`,`VolumeInfo`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Tags` (`Tags`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Identifierfulltext` (`IdentifierWODash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3246566 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
CREATE TABLE `LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reference` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `data` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `crcomment` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `groupname` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `code` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `indentation` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_cat` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_master` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_master_cat` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_override_cat_moddetails` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_override_cat_timestamp` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_override_cat` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `pageno` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_escalated` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `history` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `history_classification` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_esc_start` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_esc_start_type` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `callCore` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d1` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d2` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d3` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d4` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d5` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d6` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d7` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d8` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d9` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d10` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d11` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `d12` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `indentation` (`indentation`),
  KEY `callCore` (`callCore`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `specialtag` (`specialtag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=496218 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
    
    | a_sg1lib | CREATE TABLE `a_sg1lib` (
  `ida` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `classifybyoclc_respcode` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `classifybyoclc_timest` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `isbn` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `choseStatus` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `choseStatus2` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `choseStatusSpecial` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `choseStatusMarker` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `subtitle` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `publisher_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `imprint_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `publication_date` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `edition_number` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `authors` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `editors` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `others` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `contributors` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `is_activated` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `public_url` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `date_added` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `format` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `rating` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `engagement_score` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `university_list_count` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `published_list_count` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `award_count` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `mobile_disabled` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `categories` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `year` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `subjects` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `topics` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `topics_facet_filter` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `topics_detailed` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `main_subject` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `main_topic` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `language_id` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `language` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_rights` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `cover_image` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `related_isbns` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `file_size` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `mobile_disabled_v3` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `is_restricted` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `organisation_list` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `objectID` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `_highlightResult` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `chapters` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `Zstatus_retrieve_TOC` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `Zstatus_retrieve_classifybyoclc` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `pid` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `ida2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `withdrawal_date` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `book_id` int(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `classifybyoclc_calln_ddc` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `classifybyoclc_calln_nlm` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `classifybyoclc_fast` varchar(960) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `classifybyoclc_owi` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `classifybyoclc_fast_max` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `reference` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `crcomment` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `groupname` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `code` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `indentation` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `specialtag` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_cat` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_master` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_master_cat` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_override_cat_moddetails` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_override_cat_timestamp` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_override_cat` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `pageno` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_escalated` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `history` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `history_classification` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_esc_start` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `specialtag_esc_start_type` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `callCore` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d1` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d2` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d3` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d4` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d5` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d6` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d7` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d8` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d9` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d10` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d11` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d12` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `idmaster` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmaster`),
  KEY `choseStatus` (`choseStatus`),
  KEY `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` (`classifybyoclc_calln_lcc`),
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`),
  KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `choseStatusSpecial` (`choseStatusSpecial`),
  KEY `choseStatusMarker` (`choseStatusMarker`),
  KEY `choseStatus2` (`choseStatus2`(256)) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

I thought what makes the query so slow is the fact that one of the tables is MyISAM, and tried to change that, but even that takes forever. Altering the columns involved in the join from TEXT to VARCHAR also takes forever ;(;(. Basically I am stuck ;(

May I know what is wrong, and how can I make this faster?

Comment: It is important the exact definition of the keys (not just knowing that an attribute is on a multiple key) because performance may deppend on if it is in first position or last on a multiple key. So, upload all your key definitions, please

Comment: @nacho noted but i will exceed the character quota for the post.. what should I do in such a case? so sorry this is my first time I reach the quota

Comment: You can edit your question and if needed, delete the describe of the destination table

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY`. That output shows indexes and table structure.  And, focus on optimizing the `SELECT` part of your SQL statement first, then the `INSERT`.  Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info).

Comment: @forgodsakehold We really need for you to post the TWO SHOW CREATE TABLE requests of oJones rather than guess about where you might have indexes defined.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck I have edited the post to include all SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: @O.Jones I have edited the post to include all SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: Please tell us what goes in that "array" of 12 LONGTEXTs.  (We may want to argue that they should be rows in a separate table.)

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  In particular, I need to see if the indexes are composite and, if so, what order the columns are in.

```
RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc:  INDEX(classifybyoclc_calln_lcc)
```

If it turns out that that is really a `JOIN` instead of a `RIGHT JOIN`, then this might be useful:

```
LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY:  INDEX(callCore)
```

I suspect that most of the columns are declared larger than necessary.  Shrinking them may help some.  For example, the 8-byte `BIGINT` is *usually* bigger than will ever be needed.  `year` and some `ids` are unnecessarily (and inefficiently) `TEXT`.

Comment: I have edited the post to include all SHOW CREATE TABLE

Answer (score 0):

forgodsakehold,  We should talk if this is not clear.  View my profile for contact info, please.

Observation 1,

```
RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc.ID appears to be INT(15) unsigned 
SELECTED for push into a_sg11lib table as book_id
```

and

```
a_sg1lib.book_id appears to be simple INT(13)  (NOT unsigned and diff lengths)
```

most often we see same column attributes when moving data.

Observation 2,
RIGHT JOIN of calln_lcc = to callCore

```
RU_sg1lib_classifbyoclc.classifybyoclc_calln_lcc is simple varchar(256)
```

and

```
LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY.callcore is varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

most often we see matched column definitions for left and right side of =.

Comment: The (n) on `INT` is essentially junk, so the size diff is probably not an issue.  I don't think [UN]SIGNED is an issue _in MySQL_.  (Collation _does_ matter.)

Comment: Rick, I would be interesting to confirm 2 digits could be stripped with this situation.  Kind of like 123456789012345 might become 3456789012345 - a significantly different value.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE tint3(i INT(3)) SELECT 123456; SELECT * FROM tint3;`  --> `123456`

Comment: Until some time in 8.0, the number was used in conjunction with `ZEROFILL` to say to provide leading zeros.

Comment: Rick, Thanks.  What you have done is not the same as moving data from one table to another from a 15 to a 13.

Comment: More likely to get 2147483647,

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here to make this slow?  A few things.

- You have big tables and no WHERE clause, so this statement handles a lot of data. It's never going to be sub-minute fast.
- Your tables have many CLOB (mediumtext, longtext) columns. The way MySQL stores those columns makes retrieving and storing them surprisingly expensive.
  Your query insists on retrieving them all and storing them again.
- You correctly identified the mix of MyISAM and InnoDB tables as a possible performance problem. **But**, your table definitions show InnoDB tables, so you may have successfully converted one of them. That's good.
- You're joining on this:

  ```
  ON `RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc`.`classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` 
   =  `loc_classification`.`LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY`.`callCore`;
  ```

  It's *very important* to performance that the columns in your ON-clauses have *precisely* the same definition.
  The declaration of `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` in `RU_sg1lib_classifybyoclc` lacks both its own COLLATE clause and a default COLLATE for the table, so its collation is unknown. It is the database's default, which we don't know.

  ```
  varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL
  ```

  The declaration of `callCore` in `LOC_Classification_Text_zFULL_YYY` is this.

  ```
  varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ```

  If your database default collation is also `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` you should be in good shape. Otherwise alter the first table to specify the collation for `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` explicitly.
- It's possible you could store those [OCLC call numbers](https://www.oclc.org/bibformats/en/0xx/050-099.html) using `CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin`. They may not need to be case-insensitive and they may not contain characters outside the ASCII and western European character sets. If your call numbers work like that, you might alter your tables to use the more efficient collation. Latin-1 text takes a quarter as many bytes to store in indexes as utfmb4 text. If you need case-insensitive searching on the call numbers, use `COLLATE latin1_general_ci`.
- `RIGHT JOIN` is just plain weird. Almost everybody uses `LEFT JOIN`, reversing the order of your two tables. Do you really need an outer join like that? If you don't need an outer join, use an ordinary `INNER` join.

What can you do about this?  You didn't tell us why you need that `a_sg1lib` table. If you're using it with queries containing WHERE clauses, to find just a few rows at a time, you could create a VIEW rather than a TABLE. Each lookup will then use the indexes on your existing tables, and you won't have to copy the data.